# How to obtain the path of the application in smart device application?

Tags: c#, smartphone

I am develpoing smart device application in C#. I want the exact path of my application. My application resides on my machine at F:/MobileAppl/ManagedAppl.

So I want this path in smart device application.

Please make sure that all the functions of .net framework does not work in .net compact framework.

Can you provide me the code or link through which i can resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work well for both windows application and mobile application

```
 string path;
 path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string getPath() 
{
    string fullname;
    string myAppPath;
    fullname = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
    myAppPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullname);
    myAppPath = myAppPath.Replace("file:\\", "");
    return myAppPath;
}
```

Comment: here is a link to the above method that might be useful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229654.aspx

Comment: After deploying the application on emulator it is giving the path as "/Program files/managedappl". But I want the path as "F:/MobileAppl/ManagedAppl". What should I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
 string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

this code will not return correct path .

My Application path is D:/Test/MobilApplication.

While executing above code it shows simply "//Program files//MobilApplication" like that.